# use macro variable in URL in R

Tags: r, rscript

I have this in R

```
#URL Link:
URL<-"www.insert.com/wer/date?begin=**2017/06/19/00**&end=**today**&format=json&timezon=est&autodownload=true"
#Pull the data from URL
TURL<-GET(URL, authenticate("email", "password"))
```

Here is is question: How do insert my variable(needs to be done in R programme):

```
StartDate<-sys.date-7
Enddate<-sys.date-1
```

in my URL at Begin=startdate and end= enddate
Pelase advise on this

Comment: Read `?httr::GET` and learn how to specify query parameters like begin, and read `?sprintf` on how to include variables in texts conveniently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `httr`'s [`modify_url()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/topics/modify_url) to construct the URL to get.

```
base_url <- "http://www.insert.com/wer/date"
start_date <- format(Sys.Date() - 7, "%Y/%m/%d")
end_date <- format(Sys.Date() - 1, "%Y/%m/%d")
full_url <- modify_url(
  base_url,
  query = list(
    begin        = start_date,
    end          = end_date,
    format       = "json",
    timezone     = "est",
    autodownload = "true"
  )
)
```

Also, be careful with the case of the code, R is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much, this did help me, it works very well.
 I was still strugguling to get date format  as yyyy/mm/dd/00 (00- specifies start time of the date i.e. mid night1